# Jquery Selectator not working two jquery file include

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Selectator (ex link : http://opensource.faroemedia.com/selectator/), In this code using jquery-1.11.0.min.js. I am using jquery.min.1.8.3.js. this two jquery using time this selectator is not working. I want include two jquery file. Please any one tell me what is the problem and how fix this problem.

Comment: why are you using lower version of Jquery when there is latest version available?

Comment: Lower version using some other functionality. Now only i added the Selectator its support jquery-1.11.0.min.js..so only i getting the problem.